# C# Windows Forms code not working - Attach Event to button

Tags: c#, winforms

Could someone explain the reason why the code below does not work?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Speaker
{    public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("bravo you did it");
    }
}
}
```

The window I have designed that corresponds to this code is a single window with a single button. I have the intention to do quite an extented program, but encountering problems, I decided to start with a small sample to see what's wrong, and I see neither this simple code works. Any suggestions? When I press the button1, nothing happens at all.

Comment: have you wired event to button itself?

Comment: Please do not add "solved" to your question title. If one of the answers helped you to solve the problem, [accept it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/220538) by clicking the check mark in the left margin. If none of the answers were useful and you figured out a solution of your own, post your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure attached the event `Click` with your button. You can do it by going to designer, double click the button, it will create the event handler for you in the code. You can also attach the event handler in your Form Constructor like:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    button1.Click += button1_Click;
}
```

You can go to the designer, right click on `Button1`, click properties, Got to events and there you can attach the event handler:

[image]

Comment: Oh thanks. That's weird, the tutorial I was watching did not use it and yet worked fine. Perhaps he did it with the designer and I missed the part.

Comment: @NoobDoob, the easiest way is to double click the button in designer and it will generate and attach the event handler for you, Probably that was missed.

Comment: @NoobDoob Expanding on Habib's comment, with Visual Studios you can double-click any control in the Designer view and it'll automatically generate the event handler for what it thinks is the most common event for that control-- so you won't always get a Click event for every single control. Example; double clicking on a form itself, you get a Load event handler.

Answer (score 2):

You need to bind the button click to the event of button click! :)

```
button1.Click += button1_Click;
```