# How to select a radio button in a group box (C#)?

Tags: c#

I have a group box of radio buttons. I can create a method for each radio button of add new System.EventHandler for each controller but in Deitel's book he just created one method without any event handler and use sender to choose a radio button but I don't know how this method is called!!  I copied all the code in visual studio but it didn't work.  Can you help me?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication3
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        private MessageBoxIcon iconType;
        private MessageBoxButtons buttonType; 

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


        }

        private void buttonType_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {

            if (sender == OKRadioBtn) buttonType = MessageBoxButtons.OK;
            else if (sender == OKCancelRadioBtn)  buttonType = MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel;  
            else if (sender == AbortRetryIgnoreRadioBtn) buttonType = MessageBoxButtons.AbortRetryIgnore;
            else if (sender == YesNoRadioBtn) buttonType = MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel;
            else if (sender == YesNoCancelRadioBtn) buttonType = MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel;
            else if (sender == RetryCancelRadioBtn) buttonType = MessageBoxButtons.RetryCancel;

        }
        private void iconType_ChekedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {

            if (sender == AsteriskRadioBtn) iconType = MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk;
            else if (sender == ErrorRadioBtn) iconType = MessageBoxIcon.Error;
            else if (sender == ExclamationRadioBtn) iconType = MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation;
            else if (sender == HandRadioBtn) iconType = MessageBoxIcon.Hand;
            else if (sender == InformationRadioBtn) iconType = MessageBoxIcon.Information;
            else if (sender == QuestionRadioBtn) iconType = MessageBoxIcon.Question;
            else if (sender == StopRadioBtn) iconType = MessageBoxIcon.Stop;
            else if (sender == WarningRadioBtn) iconType = MessageBoxIcon.Warning;
        }

        private void DisplayBTN_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("This is your Custom MessageBox.", "Custom Messagebox", buttonType, iconType);

            switch (result) { 

                case DialogResult.OK :
                    DisplayLable.Text = "Ok was pressed";
                    break;
                case DialogResult.Cancel:
                    DisplayLable.Text = "Cancel was pressed";
                    break;
                case DialogResult.Abort:
                    DisplayLable.Text = "Abort was pressed";
                    break;
                case DialogResult.Retry:
                    DisplayLable.Text = "Retry was pressed";
                    break;
                case DialogResult.Ignore:
                    DisplayLable.Text = "Ignore was pressed";
                    break;
                case DialogResult.Yes:
                    DisplayLable.Text = "Yes was pressed";
                    break;
                case DialogResult.No:
                    DisplayLable.Text = "No was pressed";
                    break;
            }
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: You are simply missing the event handler registration, e.g. add `buttonType.CheckedChanged += buttonType_CheckedChanged` to your constructor, after InitializeComponent(), or add this via the UI designer in the `Properties` for that button

Comment: You have to add the same EventHandler to all your radio buttons. This can be done in code as well as in designer (by choising the eventhandler in the properties tool panel)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# Windows Forms code not working - Attach Event to button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20197632/c-sharp-windows-forms-code-not-working-attach-event-to-button)

Comment: i can add eventhandler but my question is why Deitel don't say that in his book ??